# Getting x , y Co-ordinates of the text present on the screen using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywinauto

I am doing windows automation with python and trying to right click on an audio file and select the **Open with** menu item to play the audio file with *Windows media player*.

For that I am trying to get the text coordinates, and prviding those text coordinates i am planning to click on it as follow.

```
import pywinauto
import SendKeys

# getting instance of previously opened window 
app = pywinauto.application.Application().window_(title = "My Documents").Wait('visible', timeout=20, retry_interval=0.5)

# focus the existing window
app.SetFocus()

# get the co-ordinates of "audio.mp3"
app.RightClickInput(coords = (x,y))

# get the co-ordinates of "Open with"
app.ClickInput(coords = (x1,y1))

# get the co-ordinates of "Windows Media Player"
app.ClickInput(coords = (x2, y2))
```

So, how to get the particular text coordinates present on the screen ?

**OR**

Instead of getting co-ordinates and clicing on them can we do it solely by *pywinauto* ?

Comment: `pywinauto 0.5.4` is not able to get list of files and its coordinates in `explorer.exe`. But we have a prototype using `UI Automation API` instead of `Win32 API`. Are you interested in early testing for this new functionality?

Comment: Or you may try `pywinauto 0.6.0` later (currently planned in July).

Comment: Yes Vasily, I will be very happy to test the prototype.

Comment: Great! For your needs we still have to implement menu wrappers in UIA-based code. When we finish, I'll write an example working with `explorer.exe` and let you know (hopefully till the end of April).

Comment: Hi Vasily, I will be happy to know about some examples using **pywinauto** for accessing tree like objects.

Comment: There is a [drag-n-drop](https://gist.github.com/vasily-v-ryabov/f6c6f4d94fe313be8236) example for native TreeView control. BTW, you can try UIA branch for early testing by `pip install git+https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto.git@UIA` (see also [example for explorer.exe](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/wiki/0.6.0-README-prototype)).

Comment: Thanks a lot Vasily. I will surely try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler way to do such things without pywinauto or any other GUI automation. Windows Media Player has command line arguments that can be used to open a particular file.

[MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562624(v=vs.85).aspx) describes the following parameter you probably need:

```
"path\filename"
(For example: wmplayer "c:\filename.wma")
```

It's easy to run in pure Python by using `subprocess.Popen('wmplayer "c:\filename.wma"')` call.

Comment: Yes, It fulfills the current need, but I was searching a UI way.